# convert matlab to python for reading a binary file

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

Im trying to convert a matlab script into python. The script read a binary file and reshape into a number of columns.
The matlab script is:

```matlab
fid=fopen(binary_file,'rb');
[inpar,ic]=fread(fid,4,'int');
if (ic<4) ; idata=[];return;end
nmagic=inpar(1);
nh=inpar(2);
nrpar=inpar(3);
nipar=inpar(4);


[rdata,ic]=fread(binary_file,[nh,nrpar],'float');
if (ic<nh*nrpar) ; return;end
[idata,ic]=fread(fid,[nh,nipar],'int');
if (ic<nh*nipar) ; return;end
```

The python code I tried is:

```py
import numpy as np 

inpar = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.int32)
nmagic, nh, nrpar, nipar = inpar

rdata = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.float32, count=nh * nrpar).reshape(nh, nrpar)
idata = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.int32, count=nh * nipar).reshape(nh, nipar)
```

I don't exactly know how Matlab is reshaping the data. Can anyone help me translate the code to achieve the same result in Python. A sample data is given [here](https://mega.nz/file/3I9SxDyb#SQk1ibKyMlWI0JqYdiJYjGoGLB6HaTOUTDTIO7bS1vE)

Comment: please provide a reproducible example (expected input and output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try to read the data with `open` in `rb` mod so it will be read in binary mode. Then we will use `np.fromfile` to read from the file.

```
import numpy as np

with open(binary_file, 'rb') as fid:
    inpar = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.int32, count=4)
    if inpar.size < 4:
        idata = []
    else:
        nmagic, nh, nrpar, nipar = inpar

        rdata = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.float32, count=nh * nrpar)
        if rdata.size < nh * nrpar:
            # handle error
            pass
        else:
            rdata = rdata.reshape(nh, nrpar)

        idata = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.int32, count=nh * nipar)
        if idata.size < nh * nipar:
            # handle error
            pass
        else:
            idata = idata.reshape(nh, nipar)
```